# Spotfire IronPython Loop through properties

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

How can I return the full list of document properties in a Spotfire file, using Ironpython.

Properties can be set by

```
Document.Properties["myProperty"] = "myValue"
```

I would like to do something like

```
for myProperty in Document.Properties:
     print myProperty
     #Some checks like if myProperty.Name = 'name1' then ...
```

Found this, but can't get it to work yet (it returns more then just the properties: http://www.cambridgesoft.com/support/EnterpriseSupport/KnowledgeBase/FAQ/details/Default.aspx?TechNote=2344

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

for DocProp in Document.Data.Properties.GetProperties(DataPropertyClass.Document):
    print DocProp.Name, DocProp.Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a property of the DocumentProperty object called `isUserVisible` that can help you here.

technically all the things that appear in your list are Document Properties (as in, they are "properties of the document"), and they are accessible via **Edit»Document Properties**. to get the DocumentProperties you are expecting (as in, "variables created in this document") you can run something like the following:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass

for d in Document.Data.Properties.GetProperties(DataPropertyClass.Document):
    if d.IsUserVisible: print d.Name, d.Value
```

you only need [`DataPropertyClass`](http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_DataPropertyClass.htm) for the enumeration; the same effect can be achieved with no imports:

```
for d in Document.Data.Properties.GetProperties(0):
    if d.IsUserVisible: print d.Name, d.Value
```

(note that you will stil get the `MaxMissingTimeParts` and `FiscalYearOffset` properties that are created with each document by default.)

Comment: niko, do you know if you can also do this with calculated value? Something like Document.Data.Values... ?

Comment: @Freddy so you'd like a calculated value that shows all available document properties? You can always concat the properties individually in the Value part. Or do you expect that the number of document properties is going to be changing frequently?

Comment: I would like to use values (Calculated values) from a text area in my Script.Was wondering if there was the same kind of loop to show all calculated values in a Spotfire document. But in the end I just want to use a few specific values.

Comment: @Freddy I'm not having much luck with the API docs; I don't know if it's possible. what are you trying to get in the end? you want to use the result of an expression in your IP gode?

Comment: Was going through those aswell, with no results.. I could replicate the calculations, I have for instance 1 that is the number of rows: Application.Document.Data.Tables["table name"].RowCount. However an other calucalted value has a data limit by function on certain columns, that is causing me issues